use rust-analyzer in vscode to open solana-progrom-library report a error,i need help
2024-07-24T03:48:21.317980Z ERROR FetchBuildDataError:
error: failed to run custom build command for protobuf-src v1.1.0+21.5
1 warning generated.
sed: library/solana-program-library/target/debug/build/protobuf-src-fdf5cd9e978f9b55/out/install/build/src/libprotobuf.la: No such file or directory
libtool:   error: 'library/solana-program-library/target/debug/build/protobuf-src-fdf5cd9e978f9b55/out/install/build/src/libprotobuf.la' is not a valid libtool archive
make[1]: *** [libprotoc.la] Error 1
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
--- stderr
cp: library/solana-program-library/target/debug/build/openssl-sys-85244c0faefa047b/out/openssl-build/install/lib/cmake/OpenSSL/OpenSSLConfig.cmake is not a directory
chmod: library/solana-program-library/target/debug/build/openssl-sys-85244c0faefa047b/out/openssl-build/install/lib/cmake/OpenSSL/OpenSSLConfig.cmake: No such file or directory
cp: library/solana-program-library/target/debug/build/openssl-sys-85244c0faefa047b/out/openssl-build/install/lib/cmake/OpenSSL/OpenSSLConfigVersion.cmake is not a directory
chmod: library/solana-program-library/target/debug/build/openssl-sys-85244c0faefa047b/out/openssl-build/install/lib/cmake/OpenSSL/OpenSSLConfigVersion.cmake: No such file or directory
make: *** [install_dev] Error 1
thread 'main' panicked at /Users/oker/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/openssl-src-300.3.1+3.3.1/src/lib.rs:621:9:

It's hard to tell without more info, but you may need to install a protobuf compiler
